# How to ignore all punctuations in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying the below query .

however it still not removing the character .

```
select regexp_replace(name ,'[][!#$%&()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+|(")+|(\')','') from name
```

Comment: What characters are not removed? Please share your sample data and expected output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass an apostrophe (') in the parameter, you have to double it (''), it should work like this:

```sql
select regexp_replace(name ,'[][!#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@^_`{|}~-]+|(")+|('')','') from name;
```

Here is another example to remove anything that is not an expression and sign of separation:

```sql
select regexp_replace(name ,'[^[:word:][:blank:]]','') from name;
```

if underscore bothers you, you can try this:

```sql
select regexp_replace($name ,'[^[:alpha:][:blank:]]','') from name;
```

I use POSIX syntax, more about this read here: [POSIX basic and extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended)

Comment: How to pass the black slash                                                                                                  
          select regexp_replace(name ,'[][!#$%&()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]+|(")+|(\')','') from name

Comment: Note that the backslash character needs to be escaped (i.e. \\ becomes \). For more information, see Escape Characters and Caveats: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#escape-characters-and-caveats